# How to make the predicate to replace the last occurrence of the given element in the list with the specified new value?

Tags: prolog

Can you help me, I can't figure out how to do this:  the replace_last predicate to replace the last occurrence of a given element in the list with the specified new value

```
replace_last(InList, OutList) :-
   append([[First], Middle, [Last]], InList),
   append([[Last], Middle, [First]], OutList).
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use negation:

```
replace_last(Input,Find,Replace,Output) :-
    append(X,[Find|Y],Input),
    \+ memberchk(Find,Y),
    append(X,[Replace|Y],Output).
```

Comment: Is it possible to use member instead of memberchk ?

Comment: `memberchk` is appropriate here, and is implemented in C code in swi-prolog, so is much faster than `member` which is implemented in Prolog code: https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/_SWI_/library/lists.pl?show=src#member/2

Comment: @Boooeee: yes, you can use member/2 instead of memberchk/2. Just, be aware of the difference between them (not interesting here, apart efficiency).

Answer (score 1):

Using backtracking:

```
replace_last_elem_match(Find, Replacement, Lst, LstReplaced) :-
    last_elem_match_copy(Find, Lst, LstReplaced, Tail, After),
    Tail = [Replacement|After].

last_elem_match_copy(Find, Lst, LstReplaced, Tail, After) :-
    last_elem_match_copy_(Lst, Find, LstReplaced, Tail, After).

last_elem_match_copy_([H|T], Find, [H|LstReplaced], Tail, After) :-
    last_elem_match_copy_(T, Find, LstReplaced, Tail, After), !.
last_elem_match_copy_([Find|T], Find, Tail, Tail, T).
```

Result in swi-prolog:

```
?- time(replace_last_elem_match(a, z, [a,a,b,a,c,a], R)).
% 9 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (87% CPU, 399078 Lips)
R = [a,a,b,a,c,z].
```

However, @CapelliC's solution is faster (presumably because `memberchk` is native in swi-prolog) - performance comparisons:

```
?- numlist(1, 1_000_000, L), time(replace_last_elem_match(99999, z, L, R)).
% 1,000,003 inferences, 1.469 CPU in 1.472 seconds (100% CPU, 680792 Lips)

?- numlist(1, 1_000_000, L), time(replace_last(L, 99999, z, R)).
% 200,001 inferences, 0.023 CPU in 0.024 seconds (100% CPU, 8517234 Lips)


?- length(L, 1_000_000), maplist(=(a), L), time(replace_last_elem_match(a, z, L, R)).
% 1,000,003 inferences, 0.696 CPU in 0.698 seconds (100% CPU, 1436214 Lips)

?- length(L, 1_000_000), maplist(=(a), L), time(replace_last(L, a, z, R)).
% 4,000,001 inferences, 0.453 CPU in 0.454 seconds (100% CPU, 8824459 Lips)
```

Comment: Very smart ! Just a bit difficult for a newcomer.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could use `append/3` to do this, but that seems like  using a shotgun to swat a fly:

```
replace_last( A , Bs , Cs ) :-
  append( B1 , [_] , Bs ) ,
  append( B1 , [A] , Cs )
  .
```

But is that any simpler, or easier to understand than this?

```
replace_last( A , [_]    , [A]    ) .
replace_last( A , [B|Bs] , [B|Cs] ) :- replace_last(A,Bs,Cs) .
```

[It's certainly not as performant.]

You can fiddle with it at https://swish.swi-prolog.org/p/tAnrXzKn.pl

Comment: You can show an example of requests with the first example, I can't enter data

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the fastest method found so far:

```
last_match_replace(Find, Replace, Lst, LstReplaced) :-
    phrase(last_match_replace_(Find, Replace, LstReplaced, Tail), Lst, Tail), !.

last_match_replace_(Find, Replace, Before, BeforeTail, Lst, [Replace|Rem]) :-
    match_find(Lst, Find, Before, BeforeTail, Rem),
    \+ memberchk(Find, Rem).

match_find([Find|L], Find, T, T, L). 
match_find([E|L], Find, [E|T], Tail, Rem) :-
    match_find(L, Find, T, Tail, Rem).
```

Results in swi-prolog:

```
?- numlist(1, 1_000_000, L), time(last_match_replace(99999, z, L, R)).
% 100,011 inferences, 0.028 CPU in 0.028 seconds (100% CPU, 3514803 Lips)

?- length(L, 1_000_000), maplist(=(a), L), time(last_match_replace(a, z, L, R)).
% 3,000,010 inferences, 0.177 CPU in 0.177 seconds (100% CPU, 16962407 Lips)
```